# How, $ f(x)=1/[1 + e^{1/\sin({n!{\pi}x})}] $ can be made discontinuous at any rational point in$[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that the function $f$ defined by

$$f(x)=1/[1 + e^{1/\sin({n!{\pi}x})}] $$
Can be made discontinuous at any rational point in$[0,1]$ by a proper choice of $n$.

Plz help me with this.

Comment: How $f(x)$ depends on $n$? Or $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}$ is omitted?

Answer (score 1):

By noting that $f(x)$ is discontinuous whenever argument to sin is near zero (or multiples of $\pi$) because if its $0^-$, exponent is over -inf and when it is  $0^+$ exponent is over +inf. Now if x were any rational, you could always choose any n to make the argument some multiple of $\pi$ and hence the function discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Lief's answer.

For example, for $a=1/3$ choose $n=3$ so that $n!a$ is an integer.  Then
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{1+\exp(1/\sin(3!\pi x))} = \frac{1}{1+\infty} = 0
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{1}{1+\exp(1/\sin(3!\pi x))} = \frac{1}{1+0} = 1.
$$